# python protobuf can't deserialize message

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Getting started with protobuf in python I face a strange issue:

a simple message proto definition is:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package test;

message Message {
  string message = 1;
  string sender = 2;
}
```

generated via `protoc -I . --python_out=generated  message.proto` and accessed in Python like:

```
from generated.message_pb2 import Message
```

Then I can construct a message

```
m = Message()
m.sender = 'foo'
m.message = 'bar'

print(str(m))
```

but de-serializing will not return a result

```
s_m = m.SerializeToString()
print(s_m) # prints fine
a = m.ParseFromString(s_m)
a.foo #fails with error - no attributes deserialized
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of

```
a = m.ParseFromString(s_m)
a.foo
```

do this

```
a = m.FromString(s_m)
print a.sender
```

alternatively you can do this

```
m2 = Message()
m2.ParseFromString(s_m)
print m2.sender
```

The difference is that `FromString` returns a new object deserialized from the string whereas `ParseFromString` parses the string and sets the fields on the object.

Comment: Is there a way to check if `ParseFromString` was successful or not? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: An important detail: on Python 3 (the only supported major version of Python), the input to `ParseFromString` or `FromString` should be a `bytes` object, despite the name.