# unable to deserialize protobuf bytes field in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, decode, encode

I'm passing using protobuf an hashed byte array. but while trying to deserialize it, I'm getting the following error:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 1: 'utf-8' codec
>   can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 1: invalid continuation byte in
>   field: master.hash1

the code is simply:

```
a = message.ParseFromString(data)
```

I believe it is a simple matter of encoding\decoding, but I have no idea how to do so.

This is the code to encode the data in c#:

```
public byte[] HmacSign(string key, string message)
{
    var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);

    HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyByte);

    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
    byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);

    return hashmessage;
}
```

Comment: Is your data encoded using utf-8?

Comment: This question helped solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675090/python-protobuf-cant-deserialize-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ASCII to encode your data so you have to use ASCII also to decode:

```
s = str(data, 'ascii')
message.ParseFromString(s)
```

If you prefer to use UTF-8, then change the encoding of your c# code:

```
public byte[] HmacSign(string key, string message)
{
    var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);

    HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyByte);

    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);

    byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
    return hashmessage;
}
```

And then use UTF-8 in your python code:

```
s = str(data, 'utf-8')
message.ParseFromString(s)
```

**EDIT**

If still not working, try to return a string from your c# code:

```
public string HmacSign(string key, string message)
{
    var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
    using (var hmacsha new HMACSHA1(keyByte))
    {
        byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
    }
}
```

And in your Python code:

```
import base64
s = base64.b64decode(data).decode('utf-8')
message.ParseFromString(s)
```

Comment: getting this error: "encoding or errors without a string argument"

Comment: ah ok, can it be that data is not a string but a bytearray already?

Comment: still doesn't work. error: "'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 30-31: invalid continuation byte"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157975/discussion-between-isma-and-itay-pupko).

Comment: I updated the answer again with an alternative method. If still not working the error is not on your python or c# code.

Comment: s = str(data, 'utf-8') gave me error that str takes at most  one argument (2 given)

Comment: Should work: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str